# managing multiple swarm clusters

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I would like to host multiple swarm (swarm-mode) clusters and manage them from single UI (preferably web interface)

Let me know if any such tool/platform available through which I can manage and monitor all the swarm clusters and nodes in each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

[Docker Datacenter](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-datacenter) is Docker's  product for managing swarms through a secure Web UI. It only manages a single swarm, but you can use tags to segregate nodes and workloads. That lets you have test and prod environments in one swarm for centralized management, but have sets of nodes dedicated for different roles.

Comment: Thanks. I will explore tags to segregate

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Rancher](http://rancher.com) and its [Environments](http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/latest/en/environments/). Citing the documentation:

> Rancher supports grouping resources into multiple environments. [...] Each environment has its own set of resources, and is owned by one or more users or groups. For example, you might create separate “dev”, “test”, and “production” environments to keep things isolated from each other, and give “dev” access to your entire organization but restrict the “production” environment to a smaller team.